# Starting Tomcat Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler

Tags: java, tomcat, port, catalina

I'm trying to start a tomcat instance(the only tomcat I have), and I'm getting some weird problems, I know that this error:

> Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler

is because some other application is using the same port, but if I change the port in the **server.xml** and run the **startup.bat** again I get the same error but now pointing to the new port, every time y change it I get the same error, also I check for other apps listening the same port using the command **netstat -ano | find "9080"**, I tried this on 3 different machines (2 win7, 1 win server 2008), has anyone faced this problem before?

> Feb 13, 2014 1:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"] Feb 13, 2014 1:25:22 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"] Feb 13, 2014 1:25:23 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init SEVERE: Failed to initialize
>   end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"] Throwable
>   occurred: java.io.IOException: ${jazz.connector.sslProtocol}
>   SSLContext not available at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:475)
>   ...

Thanks

Comment: The problem is with 9443 not with 9080. Also look here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460726

Comment: I just tried netstat -ano | find "9443" and no other apps are listening this port

Comment: Do you have jazz.connector.sslProtocol system property set? You can check it using visualvm. Have you tried the link I've send you? It seems that it's not a plain Tomcat.

Comment: yes, it's the Tomcat shipped with JTS (RTC server), I checked the ports using the command netstat -aon | findstr xxxx, and all of them are used by java.exe but only when the Tomcat console is opened, after closing it and recheck the ports with the same command, the ports are free, I'm really confused, because if I change the ports I get the same error but now with the new ports.

Comment: So again. Have you tried here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460726 ? It seems that it's exactly you problem "SSLContext not available"

Comment: I download Tomcat-8.0.41 from <http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi> and start it. I encounter this problem. And I follow the common solution that we can change the connect port. But I still encounter the problem. Finally I download another version tomcat-8.5.11 and chang e its port, it works.